# read from an in memory database that i have created in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I  create an in memory SQLlite database.

I then populate this with a table from a pandas dataframe.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd


# Create an in-memory SQLite database.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)


# Create a table from scratch with 3 rows.
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']})

df.to_sql('users', con=engine)
engine.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()


# An sqlalchemy.engine.Connection can also be passed to con:
with engine.begin() as connection:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['User 4', 'User 5']})
    df1.to_sql('users', con=connection, if_exists='append')

# create a second dataframe 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['User 6', 'User 7']})
df2.to_sql('users', con=engine, if_exists='append')


x = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
print(x)


print('example data is written')
```

I then want to read the information back into another dataframe from the SQLite database from a separate script (if this is possible).

How can i do this ?

Comment: how about https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html ?

Comment: This is where is was getting the original code from, but what would one point to for data that has been written (in a different script) or is the database destroyed when the script has finished running ?

Comment: Don't use in mem db...